# Excel: VBA to TRIM initial strings that vary in lengh

Tags: excel, vba

Good Day to all,

I have VBA script that trims a specific lengnt of characters and then copies and pastes the remaining characters on another sheet but I've recently come across an issue. The initial lenght has now increased and the script leaves behind characters that shouldn't. Here's the original part  of the script.

```
If Left(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3), 6) = "Emplo:" Then
ID = Right(Left(Trim(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3)), 11), 4)
Employee_Name = Trim(Right(Trim(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3)), Len(Trim(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3))) - 11))
End If
```

Originally, the initial string would read like this: **Emplo: 1234 Sample, Name**
But now the initial string varies and the numbers after "Emplo: " are either 3, 4 or 8 digits long and I can't get the script to trim the proper amount of initial characters to keep the name intact.

Is it possible to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can break it apart using the *space* character:

```
If Left(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3), 6) = "Emplo:" Then
    ary = Split(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3), " ")
    ID = ary(1)
    Employee_Name = ary(2) & " " & ary(3)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gary's Student. It worked like a cham. I just had to make change to the employee name arrays since some include up to 4 arrays. 

    If Left(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3), 6) = "Emplo:" Then
    ary = Split(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3), " ")
    ID = ary(1)
    Employee_Name = ary(2) & " " & ary(3) & ary(4)
    End If

Even tried with up to 5 Arrays and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you need to use split function effectively to get the solution

```
Var = Split(Sheets("NAMES").Cells(a, 3),":")(1)
ID = Split(LTrim(Var)," ")(0)
Employee_Name = Right(Var,Len(Var) - Len(ID))
```

Comment: Thanks Jagadish. I tried your approach but for some reason it would split the names from the IDs but when the script pasted the data onto the other sheet, it would keep the ID attached to the name and I couldn't figure out how to make the split separate them properly.

Comment: Jagadish. I fixed what was wrong and it's now working properly. The issue was with the "LEN(ID). I had changed the ID to Emplo_ID but forgot to change it in that part of the code. Your approach ignores array count so it actually splits the entire name from the ID. I just have one question tho'. It's leaving a space infront of every name, how can I fix this?